# How can I use ternary operator in ejs?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

I want to use ternary operator in ejs. The following code block is not working. Should I only use if-else in ejs?

```
<% kindOfDay === "Saturday" || kindOfDay === "Sunday" ? { %>
<h1 style="color: purple;"><%= kindOfDay %> List</h1>
<% } : { %>
<h1 style="color: blue;"><%= kindOfDay %> List</h1>
<% } %>
```

Comment: You have to think of ejs templates as being converted into print statements. `<%` is the end of a print statement and allows you to write control flow statements (conditions, loops etc), and `%>` marks the begin of the next print statement.

Answer (score 1):

The ternary operator creates a single expression and does not use `{` `}`.

It is used like `condition? a : b` or `condition? (a) : (b)` not `condition? {a} : {b}`.

If/else on the other hand, is used with curly braces like `if (condition) {a} else {b}`

---

However in your case, you can simplify your code to:

```js
<h1 style="color: <%= (kindOfDay === "Saturday" || kindOfDay === "Sunday") ? "purple" : "blue" %>"><%= kindOfDay %> List</h1>
```

Comment: thank you but i tried without {} before wrote this question, like   <% kindOfDay === "Saturday" || kindOfDay === "Sunday" ? %>
  <h1 style="color: purple;"><%= kindOfDay %> List</h1>
  <% : %>
  <h1 style="color: blue;"><%= kindOfDay %> List</h1>
  but it still not work. what should i do?

Comment: Did you try using () instead of {}?

Comment: thank you but i tried using () that you mentioned like  
 <% kindOfDay === "Saturday" || kindOfDay === "Sunday" ? ( %>
    <h1 style="color: purple;"><%= kindOfDay %> List</h1>
    <% ) : ( %>
    <h1 style="color: blue;"><%= kindOfDay %> List</h1>
    <% ) %> 
but still didn't work. i have no idea.

Comment: Probably best to stick to if/else unless its all in one line.

Comment: that or using a variable

<%
var day_color = (kindOfDay === "Saturday" || kindOfDay === "Sunday") ? "purple" : "blue"
%>

<h1 style='<%= `color:${day_color}`%> > <%= kindOfDay %> </h1>